# ORacle SQL Regular Expressions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm looking to create some regular expressions code for some testing. In the below I have created a Constraint Check for an email address.

```
     create table testemail (username varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
     Password varchar(15) Not NULL,
     CONSTRAINT pk_usertest PRIMARY KEY (username),
     CONSTRAINT un_emailtest CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(username,'^([[:alnum:]]+)@[[:alnum:]]+.(com|net|org|edu|gov|mil)$'))
```

Is there a better way to have a constraint check when a new user creating an account?

Also, I'm trying to search a user by the name of 'Luke Haire' but my below sql queries returns no results:

```
 select * from customers where regexp_like (name, '^([L(u|i|o)ke]+)[\][Haire]$');
```

Comment: See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1509264).

Comment: Your regex misses [lots of TLDs](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) including all the country code TLDs and will not validate any address with multiple sub-domains (i.e. `jsmith@x.y.z.co.uk`). It also won't accept an IP address in the domain (i.e. `jsmith@[192.168.2.1]` or `jsmith@[IPv6:2001:db8::1]`). In the local part it won't accept valid e-mail addresses like `email.with+symbol@example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your first question.  A check constraint is the best way to have a check constraints.  That is why databases support it.  There are worse ways, such as triggers, but typically the best way is using this built-in, standard capability.

Your specific constraint seems too constrained.  Email addresses commonly contain "." and "-" as well.

As for the second question, the problem is the suffix.  So try:

```
select *
from customers
where regexp_like(name, '^([L(u|i|o)ke]+)[\][Haire]@.*$');
---------------------------------------------------^
```

I should add that I prefer the above to the equivalent:

```
where regexp_like(name, '^([L(u|i|o)ke]+)[\][Haire]@');
```

The issue is the difference between `like` and `regexp`.  `like` always matches the entire string.  So, under most circumstances, I prefer to have regular expressions emulate this by explicitly having the beginning and end.  This is to avoid confusion.  I use like for simpler searches and regular expressions for more complex ones.

However, I would still expect this to get no matches because `\` is not an allowed character before the `@`, according to the check constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and helped tremendously. Good point about how email addresses contain - and . as well. What are your thoughts for having a simple check constraint that would only check having a valid email address that will check letters, numbers, special characters before the @ and .com or similar? Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't return any rows because you have two mistakes in your pattern.

Second expected character, according to your pattern is \ so in character list
`[\]` you should add 
space `[\ ]` or `[\[:space:]]`.
You are missing quantifier for [Haire] character list.
At the moment your pattern works like:

```
regexp_like ('Luke Haire', '^([L(u|i|o)ke]+)[\](H|a|i|r|e)$')
```

One possible pattern for your entry string is:

```
 regexp_like (name, '^([L(u|i|o)ke]+)[\ ][Haire].*$')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and helped tremendously. I was able to use the select statement with the regexp_like.